# Not showing the URL pattern option

Tags: 8, path-aliases

Drupal 8, When we go to URL aliases section, there is no URL pattern option like Drupal 7.

Do I need to install any other modules to have this feature available?

**Edit**

Added screenshot

**Drupal 8**
[image]
**Drupal 7**
[image]

Comment: May you show a screenshot of what you see? I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @kiamlaluno updated the ticket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those options are provided by the [Pathauto module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto).

At time of writing, the Drupal 8 version of Pathauto is unfortunately not usable; you can follow progress [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2573683)

Comment: There is an unofficial D8 port which is pretty stable imho https://github.com/md-systems/pathauto

Comment: Yea you are right!. But the project showing in Drupal page is irrelevant, it's a copy from D7